# How to show only 2 post from post in ACF relationship

Tags: relationship, advanced-custom-fields

After creating customfield from ACF. I select multiple articles. How can I show only the last 2 posts? Thank!

Show only 2 post from relationship ACF

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `post_object` field. With this field, you can select which objects you would like to display, when you configure it to "multiple values".

```
<?php
$featured_posts = get_field('featured_posts');
if( $featured_posts ) { ?>
 <ul>
 <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```